# php compare string by subscript

Tags: php, html

Hello I have the following script in PHP:

```
$correct = array("a", "a", "a", "a");
$totalValue = "First Name: " . $fname . "\n";
$totalValue .= "About Our Mission | Question 01: " . $S1Q1 . "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" . (compare $correct[0] with $S1Q1 choice) ? "Correct" : "Wrong" . "\n";
```

$S1Q1 is a variable which I accept from a form using radio button:

```
    <input type="radio" name="S1Q1" value="a" /> True
    <input type="radio" name="S1Q1" value="b" /> False
```

**(compare $correct[0] with $S1Q1 choice) ? "Correct" : "Wrong"** < how do I implement that in the php code.

And for the next radio choice I would compare **$correct[1] with $S1Q2**... and so forth.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will check if value entered in radio button is = to correct answer

```
$S1Q1 = $_GET['S1Q1'];
($S1Q1 == $correct[0]) ? 'correct' : 'wrong'
```

Comment: I forgot to add $S1Q1 = $_POST['S1Q1']; that I already have on the file so this will take care of it. Thanks! and it's within single quote or double?

Comment: Both single or double quote will work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/difference-between-single-quote-and-double-quote-string-in-php

Comment: From below i asked: What if i have multiple variables, S1Q1(Section 1 Question 1). So let's say i have S1Q1 S1Q2 S2Q1 S2Q2 S2Q3 S3Q1 S3Q2 and so forth, how can I check that? would you happen to know?

Comment: Try using an array for your questions name="S1[0]", name="S1[1]", name="S2[0]", name="S2[1]" ... then $_POST['S1'] will return array of responses for all questions

Comment: or you can use name="S[0][0]", name="S[0][1]", name="S[1][0]", name="S[1][1]" then you will only have to get $_POST['S']

Answer (score 1):

Main mechanism:

```
$S1Q1 = $_GET['S1Q1']; // or $_POST['S1Q1']
($correct[0] == $S1Q1 ) ? 'Correct' : 'Wrong'
```

Using loop:

```
if( isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST) ){
   foreach($_POST as $key => $val ) {
       $index = (int) str_replace('S1Q', '', $key ); // 1, 2, 3..
       $result = $val == $correct[ $index - 1 ] ? 'Correct' : 'Wrong';
   }
}
```

Use `$result` in you code.

Comment: OP wants to match against `$correct[0]` which isn't an array, but a string.

Comment: This would check to see if the post is equal to the correct answer for any question. OP wants to check to see if it's equal to one specific question.

Comment: What if i have multiple variables, S1Q1(Section 1 Question 1). So let's say i have S1Q1 S1Q2 S2Q1 S2Q2 S2Q3 S3Q1 S3Q2 and so forth, how can I check that?

Answer (score 1):

You can access to the var with $_POST and/or $_GET

```
 $S1Q1 = $_POST['S1Q1']
```